# Copy files from all computers in a domain using SCCM or GPO

Tags: group-policy, sccm

We are trying to copy a file from a folder in all computers in the AD to a centralized location. Is there a way we can do this using SCCM or GPO?

Answer (score 1):

Sure there are no tricks to this, write a PowerShell scripts to copy the file to a central server. The only thing you have to watch out for is security. CM runs a local system account (aka computer account), as long as it has access to the share, all is good.